# VBA Excel "contains" операторы?

Tags: excel, vba

Нужно, чтобы при сравнивании двух похожих строчек String.

Например: If "йцуке" содержит/включает "йцу" = true.

В других есть такой метод "contains", а в VBA как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В VBA для этих целей есть функция InStr. Используется как

```
InStr([start,] string1, string2[, compare])
```

где `start` - необязательный параметр, указывающий начальную позицию для поиска (по умолчанию с первого символа)
`string1` - строка, в которой осуществляется поиск
`string2` - искомая строка
`compare` - необязательный параметр, указывающий метод сравнения (бинарное, текстовое или сравнение информации в базах данных (только для Access)). По умолчанию используется бинарное сравнение.

Возвращаемые значения функции:
`NULL` - если любая из строк `NULL`,
0 - если `string1` пустая строка либо `string2` не найдена, либо `start` больше длины строки `string1`,
`start` - если `string2` пустая строка,
если строка `string2` найдена внутри строки `string1`, то возвращает позицию, в которой найдено совпадение.

Пример использования

```
Function contains(string1 As String, string2 As String, Optional start As Integer = 1, _
        Optional compare As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As Boolean
    ' функция проверки вхождения строки string2 в строку string1 без учёта регистра  
    ' если string2 - пустая строка, то возвращается False
    Dim findPosition As Integer

    contains = False
    findPosition = InStr(start, string1, string2, compare)
    If Len(string2) > 0 And findPosition >= start Then contains = True
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
    Dim start As Integer

    str1 = "absqwerty"
    str2 = "qwer"
    MsgBox contains(str1, str2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к уже опубликованному ответу:

Можно использовать оператор `like`:

```
if "йцуке" like "*йцу*" then
    msgbox "Содержит"
else
   msgbox "Не содержит"
end if
```

Данный оператор чувствителен к регистру, поэтому если нужно опустить чувствительность, можно использовать один из двух вариантов:

1. `Option Compare Text`
2. Использовать `Lcase` либо `Ucase`, т.е. на вашем примере может выглядеть так:

   `if Lcase("йЦуКе") like Lcase("*ЙцУ*") then ....`

Answer (score 0):

Повторюсь, но все же. InStr, Like - для строки. Если же массив строк, то используется Filter

**Filter** (<массив Строк>, <строка Поиск>[, <включение>] [, <сравнение>]) - просматривает массив строковых значений и ищет в нем все подстроки, совпадающие с заданной строкой.
*Эта функция имеет четыре аргумента:*
<строка Поиск> - искомая строка;
<включение> - параметр (boolean значение), который указывает, будут ли возвращаемые строки включать искомую подстроку или, наоборот, возвращаться будут только те строки массива, которые не содержат искомой строки в качестве подстроки;
<сравнение> - параметр, определяющий метод сравнения строк.